# iOS scroll view in interface builder with auto layout is not scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to use a scroll view to my content. I have followed the guides on the internet, and yet, the view is not scrolling.
I am attaching a screenshot of the constraints and view controller hierarchy.

[image: VC hierarchy]

Also, I have tried programatically to change the content size of the scroll view, and it did scroll, but it was weird, as some of the content looked like it was outside the VC's view, and also was not responding to touch, so this can also help figure the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the viewController's simulated size to freeform?

Comment: Is your content larger than the scrollview? If it's not, it won't scroll (doesn't need to).

Comment: because your content view height is equal to the main superview of scrollview height....remove the last constraint and if you get warning or error then configure the height of content view according to its inner content.. tell me if you did not get what I said

Comment: I think you have set the height and width of the content view as a constant. That means no matter what, the content view height and width is going to be the same. If you want a vertical scroll, put the contentview and the view(view behind the scroll view) equal heights. Then jus click on that constraint and set the priority to low(250)

Comment: @M.K. , What do you mean by configuring the height of content view according to its inner content? what constraint to add? I am getting an error after removing the constraint.

Comment: put your single screen in a view controller of a sample project and send me link...you can upload on github...i will edit and i will describe you also in chat if you want.

Comment: configuring height according to inner content height means vertically all inner elements connected and bottom constraint of bottom last element to bottom of content view and same as top of top most element connected to top of content view. simply height of content view should depend on inner contents collaborated height

Comment: OK I think I got it, I set a constraint for the height of the content view, and its scrolling now but I still don't see the button. I think it's other issue though.

This is what you meant ?

Comment: Got it! I have made what you asked and now it is working good! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set the height and width of the content view as a constant. That means no matter what, the content view height and width is going to be the same. If you want a vertical scroll, set the constraint for the contentview and the scroll view equal heights. Then jus click on that constraint and set the priority to low(250)

[image]

Comment: Nope sorry, that didn't work as I didn't use a constant. thanks anyway